# evolution 3.2 not deleting duplicate email account

Tags: evolution

After upgrading Ubuntu 11.04 to 11.10
I found duplicate mail accounts in the Evolution listing. 
I removed the unwanted ones, both unsubscribing  and deleting them 
for Preferences/Account. I also wiped out completely the 
./local/share/evolution/mail folder. Apparently they seem gone.
However, the problem is that every time Evolution is restarted the duplicate account show up again and I have to repeat the cancellation procedure.
In particular the problem is manifest with only one of my two  gmail accounts ( the one which is the default mail account)

What's the cause of this behaviour? Did anyone experience similar issues?

I'll take the wiping out of the ./local/share/evolution folder as a last option, since I'd like not to lose all my email accounts configurations.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess: check out the 'online accounts' preferences in system preferences to see if gmail is configured there. To do this, first click on the 'gears' icon in the top right of the screen, select 'system settings', and find 'online accounts'. Is your gmail account there? If it is, just delete it and try again in Evolution.